# Указатель С++ и динамическая память

Tags: c++, указатели

Доброго всем времени суток!
Хочу уточнить, правильно ли я понимаю теорию.
Имеем такое:

```
int *p = new int;
*p = 5;
cout << p;
cout << &p;
cout << *p;
```

Правильно ли я понимаю:

1. при удачном выполнении операции [`int *p = new int;`] у нас в оперативной памяти происходит выделение *диапазона ячеек*, достаточного для хранения переменной типа `int`?
2. при этом указатель p хранится в стеке **как локальная переменная** и хранит выделенный в куче адрес этого самого *диапазона ячеек* и именно его мы видим через [`cout << p`]
3. а через [`cout << &p`], получается, мы видим адрес этой нашей **локальной переменной?**

Спасибо!

Comment: да, все выглядит правдоподобно.

Answer (score 2):

Да, да и да. Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Выглядит правдноподобно. Но есть "мелочи".

В втором пункте обычно в переменной будет хранится адрес начала "диапазона памяти". Некоторые менеджеры памяти могут выделить немного больше памяти и дать указатель в середину. По "отрицательным" смещениям может хранится различная информация для менеджера памяти. Но это детали реализации и обычного программиста они интересуют только когда "все сломалось".

Но самое главное - Вы забыли пункт 4 - также в этом коде есть утечка памяти:)